# How to control 30 stepper motors using Arduino?

Tags: shields, stepper, stepper-motor

To prototype my project, I'm going to use an Arduino. I need to control 30 step motors.

4 of these step motors should always be ready to work, no matter other motors are working or not. But the other 26 motors never work in the same time (only one or none of these 26 step motors work at the same time).

So I'm looking for a fast and cheap way to prototype my machine and I need your advice.

I think a CNC Shield or 4 EasyDriver can do the job for controlling those 4 step motors (those motors which need to be ready to work at any moment of time).

But for the other 26 step motors (which can be controlled one by one) is there a way to avoid using 26 EasyDrivers or stacking several other shields? Is there a way to control those 26 step motors using a single driver?

Thanks.

Comment: @jsotola, Thanks for reply. There is no need to stay in holding position. When one of those 26 step motors are rotated for _n_ steps, we can safely turn the motor off until the next time we need it. So we can use the driver for another motor.

Comment: this question is not really about the Arduino, but about stepping motor drivers and should be moved to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=123547.0, https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?2,196989, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266213/multiplexing-h-bridge-stepper-control, etc. Personally... meh. You can get a cheap stepper controller for like $1-1.5 w/o even trying, and it'll be easier to multiplex the control signals rather than the driver output.

Comment: Have a microcontroller + driver per motor and network them all together to a master controller.